# Hash table for objects in c++

Tags: c++, class, hash

I'm trying to make a hash table for simple objects unfortunately when I compile this code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class K {
   public:
      int n;
      K(int n): n(5) {}
};

class hTab {
      string * a;
      K * k;
      int r;
   public:
      hTab(int n): a(new string[n]), k(new K[n]), r(0) {}
      ~hTab() { delete [] k; delete [] a; }
      int getId(string s) {
         int i = 0;
         while (i != r && s != a[i]) {++i;}
         return i;
      }
      K & operator [] (string s) {
         a[r] = s;
         ++r;
         return k[r-1];
      }
      const K & operator [] (string s) const {return k[getId(s)];}
};

int main() {
   hTab tab(20);
   K a(5);
   tab["sth"] = a;
   cout << tab["sth"].n;
   return 0;
}
```

following errors pops up.

```
In constructor 'hTab::hTab(int)'
16 error: no matching function for call to 'K::K()'
In member function 'const K& hTab::operator[](std::string) const'
28 error: passing 'const hTab' as 'this' argument of 'int hTab::getId(std::string)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I will be grateful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 The first error: `no matching function for call to 'K::K()'` comes from your constructor for hTab. Specifically: `new K[n]`

In C++ when when you make an array of classes, C++ will automatically call the default (empty) constructor. In this case, it is `K()`. Since you already defined a constructor for K, the default constructor doesn't exist, so you get an error.

To fix it just define a new function `K::K()` to do what you think the default should be.

EDIT: Also, something to note is that in `K::K(int n)`, the parameter `n` does absolutely nothing at the moment. The member variable `n` will always end up as 5 anyways. If you just made it `K::K()` that would also fix your problem.

2 The second error: `passing 'const hTab' as 'this' argument...` comes form your `operator[] (string s) const` function.

Since you ended the function declaration in `const` it can't change anything in the class, or call non-const functions. `getId(string s)` is not a const function, so you are not allowed to call it in there. (Even though it doesn't change anything, C++ isn't smart enough to know that...).

This fix is simple, add a const to the end of the declaration of `getId`:

```
int getId(string s) const
```